# Nx.dev doesn't show my newly created plugin

Tags: nx.dev

I'm trying to understand and use [nx.dev dev tools](https://nx.dev/react)
Basically what I'd like to do now is to create a custom plugin.

So I first installed the @nrwl/nx-plugin plugin which allows to build custom plugins.
Then I created a test plugin using the command:

```
nx g @nrwl/nx-plugin:plugin my-plugin
```

Done that, I built the plugin:

```
nx run my-plugin:build
```

Then I published to npm (my local npm repository of course, hosted via [Verdaccio](https://verdaccio.org/))

```
npm publish ./dist/libs/my-plugin --registry http://localhost:4873
```

Done that I installed my brand new plugin as you would do with any other nx plugin:

```
npm install -D @webtest/my-plugin --registry http://localhost:4873
```

Please note that `@webtest` is the name of my nx.dev workspace

The command is successful, but when I do:

```
nx list
```

I don't see it in the installed plugin list. All I get is:

```
  NX  Installed plugins:

  @nrwl/cypress (builders,schematics)
  @nrwl/jest (builders,schematics)
  @nrwl/linter (builders)
  @nrwl/node (builders,schematics)
  @nrwl/nx-plugin (builders,schematics)
  @nrwl/web (builders,schematics)
  @nrwl/workspace (builders,schematics)
```

I would expect a `@webtest/my-plugin` on there. What am I missing here? Should the custom plugin appear in the installed plugin list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like there's a regression where only core and community plugins are listed when running `nx list`. This will be patched in 9.4.